# Script works when using "run in terminal" not when using "run"

Tags: scripts

I am using a script which is basically identical to the first one in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4783182/7238575. It works perfectly when run in the terminal or using the option "Run in terminal" (when setting the preference to asking what to do when double clicking a script in Nautilus). However, when I just "Run" it (or when the preference is set to run) it does not work.

What is the difference and what is going on? How can I make the script work with the default "Run" (I would prefer to keep the preference to always use "Run" so that I can just double click to run the script without any dialogs.)

Comment: This is quite a common problem you'll find lots of answers on SO, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430311/bash-script-not-working-when-run-outside-terminal. As it's a general issue with running scripts I'd ask this question there (after trying a couple of solutions first). As answer below says it's likely environment. I'd check your #! is correct and pass through `shellcheck` too.

Comment: Seems spellcheck does not support a script using expect:
"#!/usr/bin/expect
^-- SC1071: ShellCheck only supports sh/bash/dash/ksh scripts. Sorry!"

Also how do I fix the environment issue. The other answer doesn't really say either. Is it possible to just add something like .bashrc to my script so that it first loads things so that it is in the same environment?

Answer (score 1):

In your script make sure you set up all environment variable you need, and specifically make sure you set the PATH variable.

Comment: I don't know what setting the PATH variable would mean, but would sourcing .bashrc or some file work to recreate the same environment?

Comment: Possibly, but .bashrc is often not designed to be run repetitively, and sometimes assumes its being run in a terminal. However, you may well have added path variable in .bashrc or in .profile.

Essentiall PATH is an environment variable that instructs the OS which directories to search, and in which order, in order to find a program or sometime a library. (Though there is a better environment variable for library files, some applications still use PATH). A Typical usage might be: 

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/opt/app1/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH

export PATH